# how to work with date picker in xamarin android ui test automation

Tags: c#, xamarin-studio, ui-testing

Im working in xamarin android UI automation, I[image] just wanted to know how to select a particular date from android date picker

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest route to go is to use the Xamarin test recorder:
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/testrecorder/?ide=xs

If you are using Visual Studio, the tool is still in preview and requires a Visual Studio Enterprise subscription:
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/testrecorder/?ide=vs

The Test Recorder allows you to interact with your app and a Test will be generated based on your interactions.

Another thing you can do is use the Repl() method to open a Terminal (Mac)/ Command Line (Windows) instance where you can examine the visual tree and find all of the elements on the screen. See:
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/uitest/working-with/repl/

Once in the REPL, you can use the `tree` command to see all visible UI elements in a Json format that shows you the type and some properties of the visual elements. You can also execute any query just as you would in your UITest project so you can see what results you get from a query.

Comment: The repl does not work for this because it reads the date picker as an individual element, so interacting with can't be done. The test recorder will let you pick a date, but the code cannot be used on a different date picker

Comment: @FrankAnderson you have to tap on it (or try to call EnterText) to trigger the date picker popup. As a result, new elements will appear in the tree and you can select them